# When is it established that Laurie Strode is Michael Myers' sister?

Tags: chronology, halloween

So far as I can tell, in the original 1978 film, Laurie Strode is chased by Michael for no apparent reason aside from "that's what he does."

Yet in all wiki sources I can find, it's clearly established that Laurie Strode is his sister Cynthia Myers, who was adopted out to the Strode family after he murdered their mutual sister Judith, and after their parents die in a car accident (I also am not sure when *that* was established in the films.)

In what movie is this back history established? I couldn't find a distinct source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It got established in [Halloween II (1981)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_II_%281981_film%29), the same link present the full story of the film.

> In Film, Marion tells Loomis that Laurie Strode is Michael Myers's younger sister.

It's better to go through it again to get to know the exact storyline.